# PowerDesigner error by generating physical model: 'Existence of attribute'

Tags: java, class, uml, diagram, powerdesigner

I have the error named 'Existence of attribute' when I try to generate the physical data model. So, what is it about? Google isn't helping :(

And how can I generate the Java classes after I generate the physical data model?

Comment: Which generation? You're speaking of Classes, so I guess from Object-Oriented Model to Physical Data. Correct?

Comment: Or maybe you're starting from a Conceptual Data Model, which actually has a "Existence of attributes" meaning that you have some empty Entities, which would give empty Tables after generation (no Dependent relationship, no Identifier migrated from a generalization parent...).

Comment: I just deleted and added again the ID, primary key, and it works now.